# Conditional Inheritance in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have **different layouts** depending on the user. This triggers the following error:
`"Multiple extends tags are forbidden"`. How can I manage to use different layouts depending on the role of the user?

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER_ONE') %}

{% extends "AcmeUserBundle::layout_user_one.html.twig" %}

{% elseif is_granted('ROLE_USER_TWO') %}

{% extends "AcmeUserBundle::layout_user_two.html.twig" %}

{% endif %}
```

### EDIT

Here is the answer. I will use the case of 3 users in case people wonder how to do this. In this case `admin` has also `userOne` and `userTwo` privileges in case someone wonders about the `else` statement. I use `Conditional Inheritance` in this case, but as suggested in one of the answer, `Dynamic Inheritance` might be more readable.

```
{% set admin = false %}

{% set userOne = false %}

{% set userTwo = false %}

{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}

    {% set admin = true %}

{% else %}

    {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER_ONE') %}

        {% set userOne = true %}

    {% elseif is_granted('ROLE_USER_TWO') %}

        {% set userTwo = true %}

    {% endif %}

{% endif %}

{% extends admin ? "AcmeUserBundle::layout_admin.html.twig" : userTwo ? "AcmeUserBundle::layout_user_two.html.twig" : "AcmeUserBundle::layout_user_one.html.twig" %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [Conditional Inheritance](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html#conditional-inheritance) section in the docs.

If you need more than two options, see the [Dynamic Inheritance](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html#dynamic-inheritance) section:

```
{% set parent = 'defaultLayout.html.twig' %}
{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
    {% set parent = 'userLayout.html.twig' %}
{% elseif is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    {% set parent = 'adminLayout.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}

{% extends parent %}
```

Comment: Yep, this works! I have suggested an other answer in my question. Thanks for your help. Question solved!

Answer (score 1):

You should have two different templates

```
#user_one.html.twig
{% extends "AcmeUserBundle::layout_user_one.html.twig" %}
```

and

```
#user_two.html.twig
{% extends "AcmeUserBundle::layout_user_two.html.twig" %}
```

Then you should have one "entry" point - some `user.html.twig`, in which you'll decide:

```
#user.html.twig
{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER_ONE') %}
    {% include "AcmeUserBundle::user_one.html.twig" %}
{% elseif is_granted('ROLE_USER_TWO') %}
    {% include "AcmeUserBundle::user_two.html.twig" %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: After a test, this doesn't work because extending  user.html.twig does not mean I extend the according layout for the user. Here, I need to extend the according layout. Conditional inheritance is the solution.